# Big query STRING_AGG() Multiple fields produces an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My query look like this

```
 SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT column1) AS mobile,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS country,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT language) AS language,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT address) AS address,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT model) AS model,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT car) AS car,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT class) AS class,
    home_email,
    buisness_email,
    MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
  FROM
    user
  GROUP BY
    id,
    home_email,
    buisness_email
```

When I run this query on my 2TB table in bigquery and set query settings to export the output to a table it produces an error
Note: when i run it on 500 GB data size it works fine

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job.

So How can I solve this please?

Also after this I will need to run the same query on a this table union with another 1TB table

Answer (score 1):

I can perform a proposition (but I don't know if it works, I don't have a big enough dataset. So, if not, i will delete this "answer-try")

The idea is to split the agg into different subqueries. and then to merge all these sub parts.

```
WITH agg_mobile AS (
 SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT column1) AS mobile,
    home_email,
    buisness_email,
    MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
  FROM
    user
  GROUP BY
    id,
    home_email,
    buisness_email
),
agg_country AS (
 SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS country,
  FROM
    user
  GROUP BY
    id,
    home_email,
    buisness_email
)
....
SELECT agg_mobile.*,
       agg_country.country, 
       ....
FROM agg_mobile 
  LEFT JOIN agg_country ON agg_mobile.id = agg_country.id 
  LEFT JOIN .....
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a good idea. I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: I've tried this
SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT students_ids) AS students_ids,
  MAX(date) AS date
FROM
  students,
  UNNEST(students_ids) AS students_ids
WHERE
  students_ids != " 1111"
GROUP BY
  id;

------ and still not working